# Applescript Facetime OS Ventura not working, please help?

Tags: applescript, facetime

I need to make automatic FaceTime call from a Python script. I made this first version of an AppleScript to call FaceTime, but its not working.  It only show the FaceTime app but it does not make the call.

Can you please help me to understand the issue and fix the code?

Here is the code I found on the net.

```
on run {}
    set phone_num to "Phone to call"
    do shell script "open tel://" & quoted form of phone_num
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat until (exists window 1 of application process "Notification Center")
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        click button "Call" of window 1 of application process "Notification Center"
    end tell
end run
```